# How to give different styles to list items based on a certain condition?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm building a list of strings with an adapter, how can I apply a different layout property to these items based on a certain condition?

For example, suppose that you need to check if the text of a list item contains a specific word and then, based on the result of the test, you want to, say, increase or decrease its margin (if this can make any sense :D ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a adapter like the following. here only background colors are changed, try changing layouts there depending on u r condition....

```
    public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    private int[] colors = new int[] { 0x30FF0000, 0x300000FF };

    public SpecialAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> items, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, items, resource, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
      int colorPos = position % colors.length;
      view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
      return view;
    }
}
```

for more details check this link http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/

Comment: Noob question: if my activity extends ListView, can I still make this work?

Comment: Ok, I understood that. Anyway, another question: what if my condition involves a part of the text of the list item? I've edited the question to make this point clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ContextThemeWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html) in order to provide different themes based on your certain conditions.